# Android Google+ Login issue

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

Followed this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

I found a strange behavior, at first startup after app clean installation it always ends up with onConnectionFailed method, and startResolutionForResult does not help.

BUT, and this is where the strange part starts, if I pause, or restart the application, it logs in like charm.

Here you can find my code sample:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/37dezieivb08eff/RegistrationFragment.java

Do you have any good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, it's all about Fragments and onActivityResult, this code snippet can help for anybody:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(childTag);
      if(fragment != null){
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      }
 }
```